# Clossing expanded child views in ExpandableListActivity

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In ExpandableListActivity is there any method to close all the expanded child views ?.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < getExpandableListAdapter().getGroupCount(); i++) {
        getExpandableListView().collapseGroup(i);
 }
```